# Como rellenar un campo de otra desde otra tabla

Tags: base-de-datos, django, sqlite, django-models

Mi intención es crear un fichador de empleado, dónde cada usuario pondrá su codigo de empleado que yo le proporcione, la idea es que coja los datos de otra tabla pero no sé como resolverlo.

Adjunto Datos.

```
Models.py

class empleado(models.Model):
Codigo = models.CharField('codigo', max_length=50)
nombre_persona = models.CharField('nombre', max_length=7)

def __str__(self):
    return self.codigo

class fichador(models.Model):
    Codigo =  models.CharField('codigo', max_length=50)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    nombre_persona = models.ForeignKey(empleado, related_name='nombre', default="", max_length=50, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    tipo = models.CharField(choices=OPCIONES_TIPO,
                            max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)

Views.py

class fichador_view_entrada(CreateViewEntrada):
    model = fichador
    fields = ['Codigo']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['entrada'] = fichador.objects.all()
        return context
urls.py

 #entrador
path('entrada/', views.fichador_view_entrada.as_view(), name='entrada')


Vista.html
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{ form.as_p }}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="upload">Aceptar</button>
                    </form>
```

Lo que quiero es lo siguiente: que cuando yo introduzca el codigo en la vista.html busque en la tabla de empleado(datos introducidos manualmente) por medio del codigo que yo le pasé que coincidirá con un codigo de la tabla empleado, recoja el nombre que tiene y lo envie a la tabla del fichador ya que en el fichador si se guarda el codigo pero no el nombre.
[image: Fichador]
[image: Tabla Empleado]
[image: Tabla Fichador Rellena]

Comment: Creo que con una [foreignkey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) te ahorras problemas y tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora se entiende mucho mejor :)

### Relación entre empleado y fichador

Cuidado que haces la relación por el nombre de persona (que podría duplicarse si tenéis más de un Manolo García —nombre más común en España según el INE). El ORM de Django se encargará de darte los datos relacionados, no tienes más que indicar el modelo que se relaciona.

He supuesto que el campo `codigo` en fichador era la referencia a empleado que no será necesario y por eso lo he eliminado. Si hace referencia a cualquier otro tipo de código vuelve a incluirlo.

```
# models.py

    class Empleado(models.Model):
        codigo = models.CharField('codigo', max_length=50)
        nombre_persona = models.CharField('nombre', max_length=7)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.codigo


    class Fichador(models.Model):
        fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
        persona = models.ForeignKey(Empleado, related_name='fichajes', 
                  on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
        tipo = models.CharField(choices=OPCIONES_TIPO,
                  max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
```

Definidas así las relaciones, puedes obtener los nombres de los empleados utilizando `fichador.persona.nombre_persona` o todos los fichajes de un empleado utilizando `persona.fichajes` (puedes también filtrar por tipo).

### Vistas

En la vista no está nada claro lo que quieres. Por un lado utilizas una clase `CreateViewEntrada` que sugiere que es de creación de objetos (parece razonable, estamos creando un objeto del fichador), por otro lado quieres obtener todos los objetos del fichador, pero rediriges a la página de inicio.

Un posible flujo sería:

1. En una url tipo `path('fichador/fichar/', FicharView.as_view(), name='acceso_fichador')` el empleado encuentra un formulario con **dos** campos: un select con el tipo de fichaje que está haciendo (entrada o salida) y un campo para introducir el código de empleado.
2. El formulario se procesa, creando el objeto de la clase fichador con los valores proporcionados.

A partir de ahí, o redirecciona al usuario a la lista de sus fichajes, o lo redirecciona a la página de inicio o …

Yo voy a suponer que lo redirecciona a la lista de los fichajes, que es lo que muestras en tu pregunta.

Con esto, tenemos que crear un formulario, una vista para mostrarlo, y una vista para cuando termine el proceso de fichado.

#### El formulario

Voy a suponer que has trasladado `OPCIONES_TIPO` a un fichero llamado `choices.py` para facilitar su uso compartido entre el modelo y el formulario.

```
#forms.py

    class FichajeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        tipo = forms.ChoiceField(label='¿Entrada o salida?',
               choices=choices.OPCIONES_TIPO, required=True)
        empleado = forms.CharField(label='Código de empleado')

        class Meta:
            model = Fichador
            fields = ('tipo', 'persona',)
```

El truco está en que este formulario es quien se encarga de todo el proceso de creación del objeto Fichador, y si quieres añadir algún tipo de validación o lógica (por ejemplo, comprobar que ese código no tiene un fichaje reciente del mismo tipo), puedes hacerlo en los métodos del formulario.

Para la vista no tienes más que utilizar este formulario:

```
# views.py

    class FicharView(CreateView):
        template_name = 'fichador.html'
        form = FichajeForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('fichador:lista')

    class ListaFichajesView(ListView):
        model = Fichador
        template_name = 'lista_fichador.html'
```

### Las plantillas

```
#fichador.html

    <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Aceptar</button>
    </form>
```

La lista puedes filtrarla mediante parámetros GET (?tipo=entrada&codigo=C56H7) para filtrar los resultados.

```
#lista_fichador.html

    {% for object in object_list %}
       {{ fichador.fecha }} | {{ fichador.tipo }} | {{ fichador.persona.nombre }}
    {% endfor %}
```

No he probado el código, así que puede tener algún gazapo, pero básicamente este sería el mecanismo.

Espero que te sea útil.

Comment: Hola Sokkian yo no quiero mostrar una vista donde se vea el empleado que es, sino que una vez introduzco el codigo en la vista que automaticamente se rellene el nombre cojiendolo de la otra tabla

Comment: hola Sokkian, cual seria la estructura del archivo choices.py. gracias